# Is there an email package that has a easy to use GUI?

Tags: 12.04, email, postfix

I finally got Postfix installed and running, but adding / removing users etc isnt as easy as a web based tool.

Is there any software packages I could install that would make managing email easier for both admins and users?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch.  I would start here:

http://www.postfix.org/addon.html

under: Run/Configuration/Queue/User management